# Switching Maximum negative and minimum positive elements of generated int array

Tags: java, arrays

I was given a task to write a java program that generates array of 20 random int numbers [-10;10]. Then i must switch the maximum negative and mimimum positive elements of this generated array.

Array:

```
public class Array

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[];
    arr = new int [20];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            arr[i] = (int) ( Math.random() * 21)-10;
    for (int i: arr)
            System.out.print( i + " " );
}
```

So, How do i switch generated elements? How should i find Minimum positive and Minimum negative elements? What methods should i use?

Comment: Can you post code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question to add all necessary informations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be more complicated, because you don't have unique numbers, but according to your question, here is a simple solution (it changes the first minimum with the first maximum).

Iterate through your array, keep `max` and `min` + their positions (`maxPos` and `minPos`). Then switch them using an `aux`:

```
    int max = arr[0], min = arr[0];
    int maxPos = 0, minPos = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (max > arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
            maxPos = i;
        }
        if (min < arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
            minPos = i;
        }
    }

    int aux = arr[maxPos];
    arr[maxPos] = arr[minPos];
    arr[minPos] = aux;
```

Another method to switch those numbers without `aux`:

```
    arr[maxPos] += arr[minPos];
    arr[minPos] = arr[maxPos] - arr[minPos];
    arr[maxPos] -= arr[minPos];
```

but it's more complicated.